# ORA-21700: REF CURSOR

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

**I'm trying to translate MS SQL functions to PL/SQL but getting this

ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete at this line:**

> ```
> OPEN param_cursor1 FOR
> SELECT wp_n from table(wp_N_Tab);
> FETCH param_cursor1 INTO WP_number;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> wp_N_Tab  WORDWRAP.wp_N_Tab_table1;
> param_cursor1 WORDWRAP.param_cursor1_type;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE wordwrap IS 
>   TYPE wp_N_Tab_row IS RECORD ( 
>   wp_n int,  r int  ); 
>   TYPE wp_N_Tab_table IS TABLE OF wp_N_Tab_row; 
>   TYPE wp_N_Tab_row1 IS RECORD (  wp_n int  );  
>   TYPE wp_N_Tab_table1 IS TABLE OF wp_N_Tab_row1; END;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :`sys_refcursor` instead of  `REF CURSOR`

Comment: what is this :**wp_N_Tab  WORDWRAP.wp_N_Tab_table1;param_cursor1 WORDWRAP.param_cursor1_type;** can you write your package code correctly and whole